# Django: Problem with ContentFile: String content is not downloaded completely

Tags: django

I'm quite new to using Django. As first project I wrote a little tool to create M3U8-Playlists.
My problem is, that long playlists are not transferred completely.

This is the stripped-down code:

```
def create(request):
    # just a dummy filelist
    playlist = ["#EXTM3U"] + 5 * ["/home/pi/music/" + 5 * "äöü0123456789á/" + "xyz.mp3"]
    file_to_send = ContentFile("")
    for item in playlist:
        file_to_send.write("{}\n".format(item.replace("/home/pi/Music", r"\\raspberry\music").replace("/", "\\")))
    response = HttpResponse(file_to_send, "audio/x-mpegurl")
    response["Content-Length"] = file_to_send.size
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename=\"playlist.m3u8\""
    # print some debug info
    print("lines:", len(playlist), "chars (no linebreaks)", sum([len(entry) for entry in playlist]),
          "filesize:", file_to_send.size)
    return response
```

The problem seems to lie in the non-ascii chars in playlist entries (äöüá). When there are no such characters, the file is transferred intact. I assume that these are characters that use two bytes in UTF-8, but writing strings to the ContentFile like I do is probably not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, while working on the problem description.
This works:

```
def create(request):
    # just a dummy filelist
    playlist = ["#EXTM3U"] + 5 * ["/home/pi/music/" + 5 * "äöü0123456789á/" + "xyz.mp3"]
    joined_playlist = "\n".join([item.replace("/home/pi/Music", r"\\raspberry\music").replace("/", "\\") for item in playlist])
    file_to_send = ContentFile(joined_playlist.encode("UTF-8"))
    response = HttpResponse(file_to_send, "audio/x-mpegurl")
    response["Content-Length"] = file_to_send.size
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename=\"playlist.m3u8\""
    # print some debug info
    print("lines:", len(playlist), "chars (no linebreaks)", sum([len(entry) for entry in playlist]),
          "filesize:", file_to_send.size)
    return response
```

The important difference is, that I don't write Strings to the ContentFile any longer, but a byte array, which I got through encoding the String in UTF-8.

HTH